# How can I most efficiently process plain text copy and pasted from a PDF into a desired format in R?

Tags: r, database, pdf, text, rstudio

So I'm trying to aggregate data on kittens under 3 months old from PDF files into an excel spreadsheet so that I can use it as data for this research project I am working on, and I've been able to do it manually so far, if I cannot find a way to automate the process I will just do it manually. However I feel that it could be made much faster with some automation, I estimate there to be 14,000 data entries in the data I am aggregating and I have done 7,000 of them. I am trying to turn rows of copy and pasted entries that look like this:

(I bolded the data I need from these entries and what the bolded data represents within parentheses next to it so that what I need can be better understood by anyone responding to this below)

**A18831909(ID number)** KITTY Cat Domestic Shorthair/Mix **1m 19d(Age in days)** **F(Sex)** Black N **1/3/2013(Date of intake)** 10:54 AM **Stray(Intake type)**
Small Cage un-numbered/Cage
un-numbered
Yes No Y ThomsonS Public Drop Off False

And turning into a format that looks like this:

```
(ID Number)(Age in days)(Day of intake)(Month of intake)(Year of intake)(Sex)(Intake type)
```

The previous example entry in this format:

```
A18831909 49 3 1 F Stray
```

For simplicity, each month of the cat's age is 30 days long, and the days after that are added on to that 30. My main trouble is that I am unexperienced with Rstudio and coding in general. There is a lot of stuff I don't need in each entry, and I need to be able to only extract the data I need and turn it into that format. I think it is definitely possible, but I just do not have the knowledge to be able to know how to do that.

I originally tried to use excel to do this, however I am not near familiar enough with microsoft excel to be able to do that, so now I am using Rstudio, partially because I want to get familiar with R for when I have to actually analyze the data. I originally tried importing the PDF and using tibble and tidyr to try and turn the PDF into something I could sort with this code:

```
opinions <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
corp <- Corpus(URISource(files),
               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
opinions.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, 
                                   control = 
                                     list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                          stopwords = TRUE,
                                          tolower = TRUE,
                                          stemming = TRUE,
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                          bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf)))) 
opinions.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, 
                                   control = 
                                     list(stopwords = TRUE,
                                          tolower = TRUE,
                                          stemming = TRUE,
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                          bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf)))) 
as_tibble(corp[["file_name"]][["content"]])

corp[["2013 Cats.pdf"]][["content"]]::"content"%>%
 print(n=10, width=inf)
```

However the PDF turned out much more messy than I expected, with artifact symbols cluttering the text and I was unable to find a way to use it.
Now I am trying to tokenize it, but I am also unfamiliar with that, and a problem with that is that I need it to be able to associate the tokens with eachother in each entry so that it is not just a bunch of unsorted text. Next, I will try and use strings to try and process the text.

Comment: @KJ
[This is what the PDFs I am working with look like on each page.](https://imgur.com/a/Fm9zSUu)
They do seem to be segmented in a way that I can work with.

Comment: https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:33fbc22c-0e03-456b-b402-c5458928dde0

Heres the link. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Also, what kind of issues can the blank entries cause? I understand that it can add some variability in the entries which might make extracting it messier. In the final format, I'll be excluding those entries from the data I want, as I am only looking for cats that are under 3 months old and I can't guess on those ones.

Comment: I have two different versions, one as a PDF and one in excel, however the excel form proved to be very difficult to traverse as cells would vary as to what data would be contained in them sometimes. I am trying to get the PDF form to work as everything seems to be uniform. Based on your comment is the problem that too many pages are being processed at the same time? I couldn't get the link to work for me.

Comment: So sorry, the link still doesn't work. It is giving me error 500, says that the site is unable to handle the request. How were you able to achieve it and in what range were those 118 extracted? It's very close to the type of automation I've been trying to achieve. When I did it manually, there were over 1300 kittens within this year that were under the age of 3 months old.